# MFMailComposeViewController in the delegate

Tags: iphone, ios, uiapplicationdelegate

The question deals with an application which uses many views in a UINavigation controller Style.

I have a simple function in my delegate which can be used by all views to plot-out error message

// In Appdelegate.m

```
-(void)popErrorWindow:(NSString *)theError
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:theError
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Report",nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
        if (buttonIndex == 1)
        {
            NSLog(@"report");
            [self mailIt:@"error name"];
        }
    }
```

Now, wanting to have a mechanism that will email the error along with some other data I have created this:

```
-(void)mailIt:(NSString *)theError {
    NSLog(@"Mail it");
    pickerMail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    pickerMail.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [pickerMail setSubject:@"error via email"];

NSMutableString *body = [NSMutableString string];

    [body appendString:@"Error XXX "];

    [pickerMail setMessageBody:body isHTML:YES];


    // Problem here:
    [self.window presentModalViewController:pickerMail animated:YES];   
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error

{
    // Problem here:
    [self.window  dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    //NSLog(@"mail was sent");
}
```

The problem is in self.window , which is not the right way to access this from the delegate, 
I still want to have the mail element in the delegate as all views can call the error alert, and I would like to have only one place for this mechanism.

How should I do it from inside the delegate, what should replace the self.window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller 
          didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result
                        error:(NSError *)error
{
    [controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

EDIT :

The `- (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)vc` and `- (void)dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated` methods are an `UIViewController` instance method, so you cannot use it with an `UIWindow`.

In order to present your mail controller with a nice animation, you can do that :

```
UIViewController *aController = self.navigationController.presentedViewController;
[aController presentModalViewController:pickerMail animated:YES];
```

Comment: what about :  [self.window presentModalViewController:pickerMail animated:YES];

Comment: Thank so far kl94,
By adding : [self.navigationController.parentViewController presentViewController:pickerMail];

I get error:
Semantic Issue: Method '-presentViewController:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

Comment: The good syntax is my post. But you can do [self.navigationController.presentedViewController presentModalViewController:pickerMail animated:YES]

Comment: ok, I assume you have a spelling error : should be :parentViewController not presentedViewController
this clears the error , but when clicked the function is called but the MFMailComposeViewController is not shown.... any idea why?

Comment: just do : [self.window addSubview:mailController.view]; and [controllerView removeFromSuperview]; And see what happen

Comment: You can also use `[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:pickerMail animated:YES completion:nil];`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps reimplementing `popErrorWindow:` and `mailIt:` in a [category](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Category.html) on `UIViewController`. This way you have access to the top-level view controller to call `presentModalViewController` and `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` on.

Alternatively you can do this in a subclass of `UIViewController` and then make your other custom view controller's subclass of that. The downside to this method is when you have subclasses of classes other than `UIViewController`